# Find two equal elements in single array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to know why, when finding two equal elements in single array, the lower bound of this is  `n log n`. I have no idea for this.

Comment: What algorithm are you using to do this?

Comment: I ask for any algorithm. Why lower bound for finding two equal elements is n log n?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario the two equal elements can always be the last two you are looking at. Without any order you have to compare every element with every element. O(n^2).

Well we don't need to be this stupid. We can of course add a order, by sorting the array: O(nlog(n)). And after then just go though the array and look for two with the same value O(n).

Better then that is hard to do, which makes the lower bound O(nlog(n)).

Comment: Hmm.. It's not a proof. Certainly, we could sort array and find them, but suddenly we could find them quicker. It's not easy problem, I think.
I could do another question from this. If I can find two equal elements in array  quicker than n log n , so I can proof that in array no two equals elements.

Comment: It's not a proof to find a single case where you find them faster then `n log n`, you need to be able to find them faster no matter the data. If you create an algorithm, and I'm allowed to read the implementation, and I can't find any one data instance that takes at least `n log n`, then that's a "proof".

Comment: Why? If I know that in array exist two equal elements then I can proof that there is no equal elements. But that's doesn't help me in finding two equal elements.

Comment: Now I don't understand your question anymore. Maybe you didn't understand me.

Comment: I think so.. So I just want to know how to proof my question:
" Why lower bound is n log n for find two equal elements using only compassion"

Answer (score 0):

Please specify your problem, which algorithm do you use?

**Generally:**

**Lower Bound**: In the worst case you certainly have to read on every index of the array, that is n operations.

**Ilustrating the problem**: If you have a restricted domain you can use another array A that will be indexed by elements of the domain. In A[i] you will store #occurences of i in your array. If you need to find the positions of the elements you can have an array of linked lists.

**Why O(n log n)**: If you have an array of elements where the only operation you can use is a direct comparison you cannot use this trick. But you can use some dictionary like data structure with O(log n) access and you arrive with O(n log n). I would like to see an elegant proof of this.

**Why not O(n)**: Imagine you have an array where there are no equal elements. Can you show this in O(n)? This can not be done faster than sorting the array if you think about it. And sorting in a general case is at best O(n log n).

Comment: Algorithm used only comparasion. 
About this "elegant proof" I'm talking.

Comment: So the major question is "Why lower bound for finding two equal elements using only comparasion is n log n ? "

Comment: You can transform it to sort. In the case there are no equal elements you have to get a complete ordering of the elements. This is equivalent to sort. In the worst case it cannot be done faster than sort.

Comment: But how ? Is that equivalent to my task ?

Comment: you can determine a lower bound by finding an individual case and showing it cannot be done faster than the lower bound. Here we show that when there are no equal numbers we have to get at least the information, that we can get by sort. So it cannot be done faster than sorting.

Comment: Why I have to get a complete ordering and why it's equal to my task?

Comment: Any deterministic sort algorithm has the lower bound of O(n log n) and there is no faster way in general case to determine if there are two equal elements in the array than sorting and then comparing the neighbours in a linear traversal.

Comment: Hm... So, I want to ask another question. Why I must to do a sort? 
That's not a proof. I know that any deterministic sort algorithm has W(n log n). Maybe I can make my task quicker.
I think about using a comparison tree, but I don't know how to transform my task normal.

Comment: Imagine you have two elements in the array between whom you do not yet know if one is greater than the other. Then i can say: these were the two equal numbers! so you cant be sure there are no equalities if you do not have your array completely ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Through HashMap you can find common element in single array with O(n) complexity. Follow this Java code.

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Main repeat = new Main();
        int arr[] = {4, 12, 4, 5, 12, 3, 1,0,6,22,7,15,15};
        int arr_size = arr.length;
        repeat.printRepeating(arr, arr_size);;

    }
    void printRepeating(int arr[], int size)
    {
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        ArrayList <Integer> comon=new ArrayList<>();
        int i;

        System.out.println("Repeated elements are : ");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (map.containsKey(arr[i]))
            System.out.println(arr[i]+"");
            else
                map.put(arr[i],arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's complexity of building Hashmap?